# UISegmentControl Customisation

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to customise UISegmentControl according to link of the screenshot(Shows is selected and News is unselected) given below:

[UISegmentControl Customisation](http://1drv.ms/1AobMp1)

1. Segment with Title and Image
2. Borderless segments
3. Tap event even if Segment(Shows) is selected - I want to perform some action if user tap on selected segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following library. It fulfilled my all the requirements. 
[PPiFlatSegmentedControl](https://github.com/pepibumur/PPiFlatSegmentedControl)

Answer (score 0):

```
[SegmentedControlName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"path"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

For selected event you can use same thing when it also on the touched state.
Only you need to change is the path of the image